# Within model with plm package

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have a question about `plm` package.

My code is:

```
fixedmodel <- plm(formula=Inv_ret~Firm.size+leverage+Risk+Liquidity+Equity,
                  data=datanewp, model="within")
```

In the `plm` vignette the authors write:

> This is called the fixed effects (a.k.a. within or least squares dummy
> variables) model, usually estimated by OLS on transformed data, and
> gives consistent estimates for beta.

I wonder then if `plm` package assumes that "least squares dummy variable" model is estimated with `model="within"` in the `plm` package? In other words, if `within` is actually "least squares dummy variable" model in plm?

On the other hand, if I refer to some other side they write:

> There are several strategies for estimating a fixed effect model. The
> least squares dummy variable model (LSDV) uses dummy variables,
> whereas the “within” estimation does not. These strategies, of course,
> produce the identical parameter estimates of regressors (nondummy
> independent variables).

So I guess the authors of `plm` package mean that they actually use `within` model but compute the unique group specific intercepts from `within` transformation later. Am I correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two estimators are computed differently, but are numerically identical, so essentially it doesn't matter. The within estimator is computationally easier since it keeps the size of the design matrix in check, and I would think that is how the within estimator is implemented. Here is some R code to demonstrate this

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
plmResults <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, data = Produc, 
                  index = c("state","year"))
summary(plmResults)

regResults <- lm(log(gsp) ~ as.factor(state) + log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
                 data = Produc)
summary(regResults)
```

Or, if you prefer, some Stata code,

```
webuse nlswork
xtset idcode

xtreg ln_w grade c.age##c.age c.ttl_exp##c.ttl_exp c.tenure##c.tenure ///
 2.race not_smsa south, fe

areg ln_w grade c.age##c.age c.ttl_exp##c.ttl_exp c.tenure##c.tenure ///
 2.race not_smsa south, absorb(idcode)
```

A proof using the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem can easily be given. Note one crucial point that for a large number of groups, that is, $n\to \infty$, the estimates of the coefficients on the group dummies are not consistent.